# How to embed youtube live message without domain

Tags: cordova, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, livechat

I am using Cordova to build app and i manage to use iframe to show youtube live stream video in my app. Now, i need to display live chat in my app too, i have found below iframe live chat embed.

```
<center>
 <iframe height="500px" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=VIDEO_ID&embed_domain=YOUR_DOMAIN"/>
 </center>
```

but my problem is i am building cordova app, i don't have embed_domain which required. Is there any solution for this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is required. I've seen many examples like this [blog](http://www.peggyktc.com/2016/05/embed-livestream-and-chat.html) and it is using `embed_domain` to construct the live chat URL.

You need to replace `<your video ID>` and `<your blog domain>` with the actual video ID and domain.

```
https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=<your video ID>&embed_domain=<your blog domain>
```